# Service Fabric Stateless Service Deployment on Individual Nodes

Tags: deployment, azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell, service-fabric-stateless, service-fabric-on-premises

I want to deploy multiple instances of my Service Fabric Stateless Service (Background Service) on individual nodes in the cluster.
So basically if I have 10 nodes in the cluster I want 10 application instances of stateless service to be deployed on individual nodes.

The deployment is creating 2 - 3 applications on single node and some of the nodes are unutilized.

Is there a way to bind the application to individual nodes?

Comment: Are we talking about applications or services? An application consists of one or more services so when you say *The deployment is creating 2 - 3 applications ...* are we really talking about 3 applications each having one or more services or not? You cannot bind applications to nodes, just services. So please talk us trough your application by describing which service(s) it has.

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationManifest file you can specify Value to -1 in instance count, service fabric runtime will deploy one instance of service in every node. This value can be passed via parameter files.